# Using external USB hard drives via a USB hub connected to a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, external-disk

If I want to connect 2 usb external hard drives at the same time, will I be able to use a USB hub? I read somewhere "Never connect your external HD thru an external USB hub!"

Is this really true?

Answer (score 2):

There is no 100% rule that applies in all situations.

For example:

- there are *portable* USB hard drives that do not require their own power source
- there are *portable* USB hard drives that do not require their own power source with some computers, but do with others
- there are USB hard drives that do require their own power source no matter the computer
- some USB hubs are powered hubs, while others are not
- some USB ports deliver more power than others

**My recommendation**

If you wish to connect external hard drives via a USB hub, especially is you're going to connect two of them simultaneously, then you should invest in a powered USB hub. By a powered USB hub I mean one that has its own power source. This way you're not relying on the MacBook Air to power the USB hub and two external hard drives simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I do have a USB hub that has its own power (plugged into an outlet). So it is ok for me to plug one external USB drive to the powered hub and another one directly to MacBook air. Once again thanks a lot.